# MapStruct String to List mapping

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

How would i map String to List and List to String?

Consider we have following classess

```
class People{
    private String primaryEmailAddress;
    private String secondaryEmailAddress;
    private List<String> phones;
    //getter and setters
}

class PeopleTO{
    private List<String> emailAddress;
    private String primaryPhone;
    private String secondaryPhone;
    //getter and setters
}
```

In Dozer and Orika, we can easily map with the following line of code

```
fields("primaryEmailAddress", "emailAddress[0]")
fields("secondaryEmailAddress", "emailAddress[1]")

fields("phones[0]", "primaryPhone")
fields("phones[1]", "secondaryPhone")
```

How i can do the same kind of mapping in MapStruct? Where would i find more examples on mapstruct?

Answer (score 19):

The example below maps elements from the `emailAddress` list in `PeopleTO` into the `primaryEmailAddress` and `secondaryEmailAddress` properties of `People`.

MapStruct can't directly map into collections, but it allows you to implement methods that run after a mapping to complete the process. I've used one such method for mapping the `primaryPhone` and `secondaryPhone` properties of `PeopleTO` into elements of the `phones` list in `People`.

```
abstract class Mapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target="primaryEmailAddress", expression="emailAddress != null && emailAdress.size() >= 1 ? emailAdresses.get(0) : null"),
        @Mapping(target="secondaryEmailAddress", expression="emailAddress != null && emailAdress.size() >= 2 ? emailAdresses.get(1) : null"),
        @Mapping(target="phones", ignore=true)
    })
    protected abstract People getPeople(PeopleTO to);

    @AfterMapping
    protected void setPhones(PeopleTO to, @MappingTarget People people) {
        people.setPhones(new List<String>());
        people.getPhones().add(to.primaryPhone);
        people.getPhones().add(to.secondaryPhone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I could see some examples here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples

Checkout this module for your specific requirement (Iterable to non-Iterable): https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-iterable-to-non-iterable

and another one here: http://blog.goyello.com/2015/09/08/dont-get-lost-take-the-map-dto-survival-code/

Not sure if it is possible to map the non-iterable to Iterable.

Comment: It's worked for one string to list mapping but i want to map primary and secondary email address to list of email address when i do that it throws same field cannot be mapped